# What is graph paper called where the grid is dashed instead of solid?

Tags: terminology, paper

I don't know what is this kind of paper call (1cm x 1cm grid)
but I am trying to find this kind of paper in A4. (After searching google for 2 hours)

What is the name for a graph / grid paper is where the lines are dashed?

P.S. I'm trying to practice my graphic designing class if anyone know where I can download it would be great. :)

[image]

Comment: If you want something to download and print yourself, why not just make a grid yourself with 1cm dashed lines and print it? Very easy in Illustrator or InDesign. I'm not aware of any specific name for dashed line grid paper or graph paper. If the reason why you want dashed lines is because the grid is less obtrusive, [**Whitelines** squared paper](http://www.whitelinesshop.se/Shop/Page/Art/pgArtList.php?iAm_Id=47) is very good - white lines on light grey paper, very subtle. [Example image](http://www.whitelinesshop.se/Shop/Image/Article/Inforuta_under_produkt.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a search for `dashed graphing paper` and found this page [Graph Paper Generator](http://www.worksheetworks.com/miscellanea/graph-paper/standard.html) that allows you to changed the lines to dashed and then generate your page.

On McGraw-Hill they have centimeter dot and centimeter line but nothing for dashed. I am inclined to just call it "Dashed Graphing Paper." I'm not seeing any standard term that I could find it with though.

Answer (score 0):

Inspiration Hut [offers a lot](http://inspirationhut.net/printable-paper/) of printable paper. However, what you're looking for is probably one of these [grids](http://inspirationhut.net/printable-graph-grid-paper-pdf-templates/).

Comment: Thanks for replying. It seems to don't have the dashed line grid I am trying to find though. :/

Comment: That's true. Sorry for misleading you. Ryan just posted a [great response](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/27010/10841) though.